# Exclude ipads and tablets form wp_is_mobile code

Tags: php, javascript, mobile

I have a plugin to disable other plugins on mobiles. Only problem is, it sees ipads and tablets as mobiles, and I need the plugin to function on these devices, anyway I can change this code, in order for it to work on ipads etc?

```
public static function is_mobile() {
            if ( empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
                $is_mobile = false;
            } elseif ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile') !== false // many mobile devices (all iPhone, iPad, etc.)
                || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false
                || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/') !== false
                || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle') !== false
                || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry') !== false
                || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== false
                || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mobi') !== false ) {
                    $is_mobile = true;
            } else {
                $is_mobile = false;
            }

            return apply_filters('swift_performance_is_mobile', $is_mobile);
        }
```

Any help would be super appreciated, btw im a total noob.

Comment: Server side device detection is notoriously unreliable. What problem are you ultimately trying to solve? There's likely a much better approach.

Comment: Ditto it doesn't work well with caching, and you'll probably end up with caching somewhere on your site.

Comment: (There's a good pay-for solution WURFL that I've seen before, which is a huge User-Agent database that's updated weekly. There may be free or cheaper alternatives. But you probably don't want to do this.)

Comment: Thanks guys. Ok, I have a quick solution going on, but as you say, server side detection isnt the best, you can see it working here: https://www.logoglo.com/

Basically, I have a slider loading for the desktop, I want it to load for tablets, but not on mobiles, ie all the scripts etc.

Is there a way of doing it with screen size? not using wp_is_mobile?